# Invisible math characters with unicode-math and ntheorem

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, ntheorem, thmtools

When compiling this code with `lualaTeX` (from TeXLive 2011),

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{ntheorem,thmtools}
\setmathfont{xits-math}
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mathfonttest}
  {\item[\theorem@headerfont $ABC$ DEF $:!?$ ]} % 1. option
  {\item[$ABC$ DEF ]} % 2. option
 \makeatother
\declaretheorem[style=mathfonttest]{test}

\begin{document}
\begin{test} % 1. option, ABC invisible
  Something. 
\end{test}
\begin{test}[triggers 2. option] % 2. option, ABC visible
  Something.
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

the first ABC, and more generally any greek or latin character in inline math mode – when preceded by `\theorem@headerfont` – is invisible and I have no clue why. What I want to do is use math code in optional or alternative description to a definition like '1.1. Definition (of $pi$)'.

Does anybody know how to solve this or circumvent it?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. When I copied and pasted your code, some strange invisible characters appeared, and `lualatex` rejected the file. Everything worked after I deleted the invisible characters, though.

Comment: Do you mean 'doesn't get printed when compiled' with 'invisible' (as I did)? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Where did your strange characters appear?

Comment: No, I mean you can't see them when you edit the code. However, I just tried again and they didn't appear, so it seems it was just a strange copy-paste failure.

Comment: How up to date your TeX installation is, do you have the bold XITS math font installed? This example shows fine here.

Comment: I just realised I use TeXLive 2011 since I needed something from TLcontrib which doesn't seem to work with 2012 yet.

Comment: I think you can manually install the new [xits version](https://github.com/khaledhosny/xits-math/downloads) and use `\setmathfont[version=bold]{xits math bold}` to manually set bold math font.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `\theorem@headerfont` calls `\theorem@checkbold` and this macro does

```
\if b\expandafter\@car\f@series\@nil\boldmath\fi
```

This is the reason for the disappearance: the font used is boldface and this causes `\boldmath` to come into action but XITS Math has *no* bold version.

If you want to use `ntheorem` and math in the theorem labels, then you need to use a non boldface font.

The most recent TeX distributions (TeX Live 2012) should have a bold version of XITS Math, so you can try updating yours.

Comment: Thanks. Now I could somehow circumvent this problem by putting `\unboldmath` in my definition of the theorem styles. But this doesn't really solve the problem for me since xits-math DOES have bold-face characters, which could be used in a bold-face font. Is there any way I could use them?

Comment: XITS math has bold version now, the example works fine here.

Comment: @KhaledHosny It surely depends on the installed TeX distribution. I'll add this to my answer.